# Mandatory field and closing form in Dynamics AX

Tags: axapta

I have mandatory fields on a form. I would like to close the form with CancelButton but I can't. Is it possible to close the form without saving record and filling this fields?

Comment: Version? Custom or standard form? If standard, what is the name of the form? If custom, check the code in that form.

Comment: Hit "X" or ESC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure the cancel button has the property "SaveRecord" set to the value "no".
Otherwise the record is validated before the button action kicks in.